# showing that a power series is not convergent and finding the radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  n^nz^{n^n}$ has radius of convergence 1, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^nz^n$ is not convergent at all.

Can I use the ratio test to find the radius of convergence? Or use $\frac{1}{R}=\limsup\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|$? And how to show that the mentioned series is not convergent at all?

Comment: I would imagine using the root test would be easier for both series

Answer (score 1):

We will procced by [the root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) for both series.

### Series One

Suppose that $z \in \mathbb C$. Then:
$$
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|{{n^n}}z^{(n^n)}\right|} &= \limsup_{n \to \infty}\left(n\left|z\right|^{\frac{n^n}{n}}\right)\\
&=\begin{cases}0 & \left|z\right| < 1\\ \infty & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.
\end{align}
$$
Thefore, by the ratio test we see that the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  n^nz^{n^n}$ converges if and only if $\left|z\right| < 1$. Thus said series has radius of convergence $1$.

### Series Two

Suppose again that $z \in \mathbb C$. Then:
$$
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|n^nz^n\right|} &= \limsup_{n \to \infty}n\left|z\right|\\
&= \begin{cases}0 & z = 0  \\ \infty & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.
\end{align}
$$
Thus by the root test once more, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^nz^n$ converges only for $z = 0$. Hence the radius of convergence of $z$ is zero.

Comment: Are you sure that the root test works for the first series, since $z^{n^n} \neq (z^n)^n$?

Comment: I have misread, but the $z^{(n^n)}$ series converges the same - will edit!

Comment: But for the second series it is required to show that it is not convergent at all so how does it have a radius of convergence zero when it is not convergent?

Comment: @newbie, Every power series around a point converges at said point. It is common to say it does not converge (at all),  even though it does still converge at one point.

Note that for $p \in \mathbb C$ $a_0 + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty a_k(z - p)^k = a_0$ when $z = p$,  regardless of choice of $\alpha: \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb C$. This is because all the terms in the infinite series are identically zero then.